# Spark History Server very slow when driver running on master node

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-emr

I'm using Spark 2.4.5 running on AWS EMR 5.30.0 with r5.4xlarge instances (16 vCore, 128 GiB memory, EBS only storage, EBS Storage:256 GiB) : 1 master, 1 core and 30 task.

I launched Spark Thrift Server on the master node and it's the only job that is running on the cluster

```
sudo /usr/lib/spark/sbin/start-thriftserver.sh --conf spark.blacklist.enabled=true --conf spark.blacklist.stage.maxFailedExecutorsPerNode=4 --conf spark.blacklist.task.maxTaskAttemptsPerNode=3 --conf spark.driver.cores=12 --conf spark.driver.maxResultSize=10g --conf spark.driver.memory=86000M --conf spark.driver.memoryOverhead=10240 --conf spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max=768m --conf spark.rpc.askTimeout=700 --conf spark.sql.broadcastTimeout=800 --conf spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode=dynamic --conf spark.task.maxFailures=20
```

Then I launch SQL queries on it with JDBC but when heavy queries are running, the UI gets really slow. I thought it would be fine if I put spark.driver.cores=12 (there are 16 in the master node) and spark.driver.memory=86000M (there are 128GB of memory) to leave some margin for the master node to be able to run other processes like the history server but it is still slow.

So I guess there are other settings that I can edit to make the UI works fine but I'm not sure what.

Those are the settings from spark-defaults.conf in the cluster FYI:

````
spark.driver.extraClassPath      /usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-aws.jar:/usr/share/aws/aws-java-sdk/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/conf:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/auxlib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/goodies/lib/emr-spark-goodies.jar:/usr/share/aws/emr/security/conf:/usr/share/aws/emr/security/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/hmclient/lib/aws-glue-datacatalog-spark-client.jar:/usr/share/java/Hive-JSON-Serde/hive-openx-serde.jar:/usr/share/aws/sagemaker-spark-sdk/lib/sagemaker-spark-sdk.jar:/usr/share/aws/emr/s3select/lib/emr-s3-select-spark-connector.jar
spark.driver.extraLibraryPath    /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native:/usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/native
spark.executor.extraClassPath    /usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-aws.jar:/usr/share/aws/aws-java-sdk/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/conf:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/auxlib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/goodies/lib/emr-spark-goodies.jar:/usr/share/aws/emr/security/conf:/usr/share/aws/emr/security/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/hmclient/lib/aws-glue-datacatalog-spark-client.jar:/usr/share/java/Hive-JSON-Serde/hive-openx-serde.jar:/usr/share/aws/sagemaker-spark-sdk/lib/sagemaker-spark-sdk.jar:/usr/share/aws/emr/s3select/lib/emr-s3-select-spark-connector.jar
spark.executor.extraLibraryPath  /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native:/usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/native
spark.eventLog.enabled           true
spark.eventLog.dir               hdfs:///var/log/spark/apps
spark.history.fs.logDirectory    hdfs:///var/log/spark/apps
spark.sql.warehouse.dir          hdfs:///user/spark/warehouse
spark.sql.hive.metastore.sharedPrefixes com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2
spark.yarn.historyServer.address <xxxxx>:18080
spark.history.ui.port            18080
spark.shuffle.service.enabled    true
spark.yarn.dist.files            /etc/spark/conf/hive-site.xml
spark.driver.extraJavaOptions    -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=70 -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill -9 %p'
spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled  true
spark.blacklist.decommissioning.enabled true
spark.blacklist.decommissioning.timeout 1h
spark.resourceManager.cleanupExpiredHost true
spark.stage.attempt.ignoreOnDecommissionFetchFailure true
spark.decommissioning.timeout.threshold 20
spark.executor.extraJavaOptions  -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=70 -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill -9 %p'
spark.hadoop.yarn.timeline-service.enabled false
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.SPARK_PUBLIC_DNS $(hostname -f)
spark.files.fetchFailure.unRegisterOutputOnHost true
spark.hadoop.mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version.emr_internal_use_only.EmrFileSystem 2
spark.hadoop.mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.cleanup-failures.ignored.emr_internal_use_only.EmrFileSystem true
spark.hadoop.fs.s3.getObject.initialSocketTimeoutMilliseconds 2000
spark.sql.parquet.output.committer.class com.amazon.emr.committer.EmrOptimizedSparkSqlParquetOutputCommitter
spark.sql.parquet.fs.optimized.committer.optimization-enabled true
spark.sql.emr.internal.extensions com.amazonaws.emr.spark.EmrSparkSessionExtensions
spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode dynamic
spark.executor.instances         1
spark.executor.cores             16
spark.driver.memory              2048M
spark.executor.memory            109498M
spark.default.parallelism        32
spark.emr.maximizeResourceAllocation true```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was having only 1 core instance as the logs were saved in HDFS so this instance became a bottleneck.
I added another core instance and it's going much better now.

Another solution could be to save the logs to S3/S3A instead of HDFS, changing those parameters in spark-defaults.conf (make sure they are changed in the UI config too) but it might require adding some JAR files to work.

```
spark.eventLog.dir               hdfs:///var/log/spark/apps
spark.history.fs.logDirectory    hdfs:///var/log/spark/apps
```

Comment: Does this mean having 2 master nodes helped increase the speed of the master? My master is running very slowly with 2300 partitions. So I'm wondering if I need to add more.